# How to implement periodic boundary conditions in a $n$-body simulation

Tags: simulations, many-body

I implemented a vanilla $n$-body simulation for educational purposes. As was to be expected, a point cloud collapses towards the middle of the simulation if the particles have zero initial velocity. To prevent that from happening I wondered if it is possible to work with periodic boundary conditions.

I tried to come up with an idea to implement such periodic boundaries but I didn't find an efficient solution to do that.

I found a few papers that talk about periodic boundary conditions in $n$-body simulations. However, they don't talk about the specific implementation of it.

Can someone help me and roughly describe how to implement these boundary conditions?

Comment: Computational Science Stack Exchange is probably a better home for this question. My own recipe is to calculate $\Delta x_{ij}=\min(|x_i-x_j|, B-|x_i-x_j|)$ for the x-distance (and similarly in the other dimensions) where $B$ is the box size of the simulation.

Comment: Assuming an attractive potential between particles, why would periodic boundary conditions change the fact that the particles want to come together?

Comment: @JonCuster Uniformly distributed particles in a periodic boundary conditions wouldn't move at all since the net force for every particle results in zero. Therefore, the initial distribution would not collapse.

Comment: Any deviation from perfectly uniformly distributed particles (including round off in your calculation) will induce non-uniformity and collapse for an attractive potential. What potential are you using?

Comment: @AndersSandberg I am not sure if I got you right. If the simulation domain is a unit square, than $\bf{B}$ is just 1?

Comment: @Samuel - Yes, if the unit square is used $B=1$.